# box.com's API to send documents for signers (through RightSignagure integration)

Tags: api, digital-signature

Provided that we have added the rightsignature app to box.com and that we have created the corresponding templates and stored them in box.com, one can send such documents from box.com to the signer through box.com's web interface. This will sign it and send it back to box.com.

I would like to know if we can do this through box.com's API rather than from RightSignature's. I can guess I can't but just wonder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Box API currently does not have an official API to work with RightSignature programmatically.  The RightSignature integration is what we call a File Action (http://developers.box.net/BoxPlatformUserExperience).  We do not yet have APIs that would let applications access those actions through Box.

Since we're continuing to enhance the API, feel free to email us at api [at] box [dot] com to discuss your interest in this API further.